# Fail2ban not banning after update to latest version

Tags: ubuntu, security, ubuntu-10.04, fail2ban

I was running fail2ban 0.8.11 which is the version installed on Ubuntu 14.04 with apt-get. I downloaded and installed the latest source, 0.93.

When I start it up, I get two error messages.

```
WARNING Wrong value for 'loglevel' in 'Definition'. Using default one: '1'
WARNING 'logpath' not defined in 'INCLUDES'. Using default one: '/var/log/messages'
```

I've seen some conversation regarding the loglevel message. It was changed from `int` to `string` in one of the more recent updates. As far as I've been able to ascertain, it's not a real problem.

I don't know whether the `logpath` error is signficant or not. I have this set in `fail2ban.conf`

```
logpath  = /var/log/fail2ban.log
```

Fail2ban is not banning any ip address, and it's not writing anything to the logs - neither `/var/log/fail2ban.log` nor `/var/log/messages`. That includes not writing any messages when it starts or stops. The service is running, though, and I receive warning emails when it is started or stopped.

I've also noticed that I get a broken pipe  error when I use the interactive client:

```
fail2ban> status
Status
|- Number of jail:      2
`- Jail list:   recidive, ssh
ERROR  [Errno 32] Broken pipe
fail2ban>
```

I have a feeling this might be something straightforward, but I'm not sure what. The installation is pretty much default. I hadn't maed any significant changes before installing the new version.

Answer (score 0):

It looks as though it was somehow related to the `loglevel`. I changed the `loglevel` interactively, as below. I then stopped and started the service (which I'd done several times before). When it restarted, it was no longer giving me broken pipe messages. It was also writing to the log and banning ips.

```
fail2ban> get loglevel
Current logging level is ERROR
ERROR  [Errno 32] Broken pipe
fail2ban> set loglevel 3
Current logging level is INFO
ERROR  [Errno 32] Broken pipe
fail2ban> reload
ERROR  [Errno 32] Broken pipe
fail2ban> exit

fail2ban-client -i

fail2ban> get loglevel
Current logging level is INFO
ERROR  [Errno 32] Broken pipe
fail2ban> stop
Shutdown successful
fail2ban> start
2015-12-08 22:48:37,343 fail2ban.server         [8583]: INFO    Starting Fail2ban v0.9.3
2015-12-08 22:48:37,344 fail2ban.server         [8583]: INFO    Starting in daemon mode
fail2ban> get loglevel
Current logging level is 'INFO'
fail2ban> exit
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a known issue with fail2ban updated from 0.8.11 to 0.9 in Ubuntu 14.04. See here:

[Wrong value for 'loglevel' in 'Definition'. #967](https://github.com/fail2ban/fail2ban/issues/967)

> A temporary solution is to run `fail2ban-client stop` and then
>   `fail2ban-client start`. It functions well...
>
> The ultimate solution is directly installing 0.9.1 on Ubuntu 14.04.